# How to format timestamp field in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have `timestamp` field in my entity, I want to format this field like that `dd.MM HH:mm:ss`.

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "payloads")
public class Payload {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(name = "insert_date")
    private Timestamp insertDate;

    @Lob
    private String value;
```

It seems `@DateTimeFormat` does not work, because format of `insert_date` column is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` in `payloads` table.

What is wrong in my code? How can I fix this problem?